# Insert Variable Dictionary Values to db

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose keys and values are updated from internet. This dictionary keeps changing the position and number of its keys/variables on every update (for some reason) but the names of keys and formats of values remain the same. Initially, I converted its keys and values to different arrays and was storing their values to database by following their array locaton, but after I discovered its variability, its no more possible to do it the same way I was doing, since the len(dictionary) keeps changing. The dictionary items are fetched from a url on every update, which sometime gives me 31 items (each item is key:value) and sometime gives me 3, 29 , 28 or even 27 items in the dictionary. So, I have made a generalization about some 'always-there' items and now I want to extract them on every update, but not according to their order, but according to their keys. Its more like: I need to search for specific keywords in the dictionary and to save their corresponding values to the variables. For instance, on one update it's keys are:

```
>>> len(dict.keys())
>>> 30
```

on another update:

```
>>> len(dict.keys())
>>> 26
```

This shows the number of items in the dictionary keeps variating. However, I have noted a list of some obligatory keys (that I am mentioning below) which are always there so I just need to look for them whenever the thing is updated. In more precise terms, I need a way to extract specific keys (probably by searching) and their corresponding values from the dictionary and to save both them to different variables so that I can save them to database. The keys to be searched are:

- temp_f
- relative_humidity
- wind_dir
- pressure_mb
- location

Thanks.

Comment: you're looking for an [`OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), and there's no need of searching a key in a dictionary,simply do `if key in dict`.

Comment: how? I think its more for sorting and does not allow me to search for specific keys..or does it?

Comment: There's no need of searching a key in a dictionary, a simple `if key in dict` can tell you whether the key is there or not.

Comment: You're using the `dict` as something it is not designed for. A `dict` is to associate a key with a value and has no real inherent facility to search for a key without having to go through the entire key list.

Comment: @khan you need to show us some of your code and data-structures to make it more clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i know the key is always there, but i am not always aware of its location. plus, if you have a variable number of items in the dictionary, its really hard to define an order.

Comment: @khan dictionaries don't have the concept of `indexing` , so there's no such thing like `location of key` in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem well, you don't need to maintain the order of keys/values in your dictionary and you just want to strip your dictionary from unwanted keys and rename the keys you are interested in. Your concern is that some keys might also be missing. I would solve it in this way.

```
new_dict = {
    'tf' : original_dict.get('temp_f', None),
    'rh' : original_dict.get('relative_humidity', None),
     # And so on...
}
```

Comment: you nailed it, bro! you nailed it.

Comment: If you are sure that the keys you listed are always present you can use `original_dict['temp_f']` instead of `original_dict.get('temp_f', None)`.

Comment: one little thing: can I bypass type errors in the code? there are some type errors as I am trying to extract, so is there a way in which I can bypass the type errors and proceed with the code?

Comment: Sure, you can do like this.
`try:;#your code; except TypeError:;pass`. Sorry but can't put newlines inside comments, substitute ; with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of normal `dict`.

Comment: its not about the order...the dictionary items are fetched from a url on every update, which sometime gives me 31 items (each item is key:value) and sometime gives me 3, 29 , 28 or even 27 items in the dictionary. So, I have made a generalization about some 'always-there' items and now I want to extract them on every update, but not according to their order, but according to their keys. Its more like: I need to search for specific keywords in the dictionary and to save their corresponding values to the variables.